# Why won't this module print

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

var someroute = require('./someroute')(router);


app.use('/api/someroute', someroute );


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000!')
});
```

This is my someroute.js:

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    var security = require('../../lib/security');

    router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {

         console.log('THIS IS PRINTING');

         security.security_function(function(err,result){
         console.log('THIS IS NOT PRINTING');
          });
    });
    //error handler
    router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(500).json(JSON.stringify({
            error: err
        }));
    });
    return router;
}
```

This is my security.js file:

```
exports.security_function= function() {
    console.log("THIS IS NOT PRINTING EITHER");
});
```

When I call the /api/sameroute url it hits the route because I can see the first console.log being printed, but then when I expect the security_function to print something nothing is printed. Then the result this function brings back I also want it to print, but it is obviously not printing since the security_function didn't even seem to run.

Comment: What's with the closing parenthesis after the function in `security.js`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is confused.  You have defined `security_function` to be a function that takes no arguments.  It should be called simply as `security.security_function()` like this:

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    var security = require('../../lib/security');

    router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {

         console.log('THIS IS PRINTING');

         // call the security function here
         security.security_function();
    });
    //error handler
    router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(500).json(JSON.stringify({
            error: err
        }));
    });
    return router;
}
```

Then, in addition, you are not using a router properly.  You are doing:

```
app.use('/api/someroute', someroute );
```

`someroute` in this type of code should either be a router or it should be a middleware function.  It is neither in your case.   You have it as a function that does `router.post()`.  That's very wrong.  That will register a new `router.post()` handler every time the middleware is called which is never what you want to do.  You don't explain what you're trying to do with this code so I can't recommend the correct code, but this code is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the callback. please replace the `security.js` file with below.

`exports.security_function= function(cb) {
    console.log("THIS IS NOT PRINTING EITHER");
    cb();
};`